# SQL snowflake: case when with wildcard returning everything with the wrong value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

The following code is returning "Control" in the column CELL instead of "Test". What am I missing?

```
Select
NAME,
case
when NAME like '%_A_%' then 'Control'
when NAME like '%_B_%' then 'Test'
else 'N/A'
end as CELL
from table1
```

| NAME | CELL |
| --- | --- |
| D119992_A64938_email_SUBMIT_kjsdfhksuere8rw987r9_B_Send1 | Control |

I have tied re-ordering the case when and adding different conditions but it keeps returning Control instead of Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underscore has a special meaning when used with `LIKE`, and it means any one single character.  Since you seem to want to match literal underscore, you may escape it:

```sql
SELECT NAME,
       CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%\\_A\\_%' ESCAPE '\\' THEN 'Control'
            WHEN NAME LIKE '%\\_B\\_%' ESCAPE '\\' THEN 'Test'
            ELSE 'N/A'
       END AS CELL
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. ChatGPT does not appear to know this!

Comment: @clocks212 ChatGPT mainly "knows" whatever it has been taught.  So I'm not out of a job just yet `:-P`

Answer (score 0):

Might look cleaner with `rlike`

```
when NAME rlike '.*_A_.*' then 'Control'
when NAME rlike '.*_B_.*' then 'Test'
```